# Typescript narrowing down within union of tuples

Tags: typescript

Say I have a function like this:

```
function foo(n: number): [number, undefined] | [undefined, number] {
  if (n % 2 === 0) {
    return [n, undefined];
  }
  return [undefined, n];
}
```

And then calling this function like this:

```
function bar() {
  const [a, b] = foo(2);
  if (a === undefined) {
    return b; // TypeScript infers b as number | undefined
  }
  return a; // TypeScript infers a as number (good!)
}
```

Because function foo returns either tuple `(number, undefined)` or `(undefined, number)`, after not passing the `a === undefined` check, TypeScript is able to infer that the type of `a` is number when returning it.

And within the `if` block, because `a` is undefined we (humans) can infer the return type of foo here as `[undefined, number]` hence, type of `b` as number. However TypeScript doesn't seem intelligent enough to be able to tell this and reports that it's `number | undefined`.

Is there a workaround for narrowing down on union of tuples?

Comment: Compiles fine as-is on Typescript 3.9.7. Is it possible this is something that was fixed in a newer TS version?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. It compiles fine, but what I want is the return type of bar function to be number (because in theory it should be), but it's inferred as number | undefined.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Do you have strictNullChecks enabled? That throws a compiler error for me.

Comment: Ah, that'll do it. Good point. I can repro now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** The improved control-flow analysis in TypeScript 4.6 resolves the issue, so the fix below is no longer necessary. (See [joematune's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71204137) to this question.)

TypeScript's discriminating unions don't keep track of the dependency between `a` and `b`, so after you destructure the array, narrowing `a` won't affect the type of `b`. To still achieve the desired narrowing, you can directly test the array element, like this:

```
function bar() {
  const arr = foo(2);
  if (arr[0] === undefined) {
    const b = arr[1]
    return b; // TypeScript infers b as number (good!)
  }
  const a = arr[0]
  return a; // TypeScript infers a as number (good!)
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUYBciwgLYBGApgE4CU2A2roaQDSLgAmRwMYRTAuogD6KVmrdpwY1iJHgG8AUIkQxgiDIgCkiAEyIAvLsQAGMolnz5JIlBAkk1BkLYduAbjmIAvq-OXrA+yKZiXC4eMqCQsAiIBACGJGhGJogQCADOUIixJDrIqGgaZC7yisqZlPo8utqMYCwOnAmu8slgaVHZpQCMXI2IXlZIBE6IAPTDiAAqAJ4ADkQAyhAkMNPp7MCkKW3Rm+KkygDmqEwAhGSuHk2p6dHtJCRl3WYW-RlDoxMz84vLq2DrJJsbtscPgJAcjqcZB4gA)

Answer (score 1):

As of ver. 4.6, TypeScript now handles [Destructured Discriminated Unions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6-rc/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions) and your code snippet will no longer error.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.0-dev.20220215#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUYBciwgLYBGApgE4CU2A2roaQDSLgAmRwMYRTAuogD6KVmrdpwY1iJHgG8AsAChEiGMEQZEAUkQAmRAF59iAAxlEshYsQkiUECSTUGQth24BueYoC+Hy9dv2nESYxLnc5bzl5UEhYBEQCAEMSNBMzRQgEAGcoAQSGAh5dZFQ0LTIwxWVVBL0DQJdUn0UrGzt410QAek7EABUATwAHIgBlCBIYQZz2YFJM+MQE+fFSVQBzVCYAQjIfCOa-NoSO7r6h0fHJ6bBZknmapZx8CXXNnflPIA)

```
function bar() {
  const [a, b] = foo(2);
  if (a === undefined) {
    return b; // TypeScript infers b as number (good!)
  }
  return a; // TypeScript infers a as number (good!)
}
```

TypeScript 4.6 RC - [[link]](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6-rc)