# A variable must has value if another variable is null

Tags: typescript

```
function makeUpdateParams(code: string | null, list: Array<{ version: number[] }>): [Error | null, number[] | null] {
  if (!code) return [new Error('code is empty'), null]
  return [null, list.flatMap(i => i.version)];
}

function updateVersion(versions: number[]) { }

function main() {
  const list = [{ version: [1, 2] }, { version: [3, 4] }];
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const [err, params] = makeUpdateParams(searchParams.get('code'), list);
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  updateVersion(params); // TSC throws error here.
}
```

Got error:

```
Argument of type 'number[] | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.(2345)
```

If the `err` returned from `makeUpdateParams` is `null`, then the `params` **must** have value. But it seems TSC doesn't know it. What I'm missing? In this case, do I have to use type cast like `params as number[]` or user-defined type guard or non-null assertion operator `params!` again?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ts=4.5.5#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYGsCmBVADgE1SkwAVUAnVZAZwAoI59MAuRaqcmMAc0QB9EYEABthAGkTCY7VgEFylAJ4AeAN6IAbpnLV4YVkOQAjbQG0AuogC+APgCUrUwFEFccv0Ejxn42csChUUtVAChERBhgRFoAQgYmO0RyTCgQciRTMEwAd0QXcjdaAHJ4zAjqRExkXChFIrsJQOFzMKSUtIymiSl2ADpgYSIAWVRcWhhEAF4bCN6tHT07cwBuEKsQkNBIWAREEAIiTAA1bV0EWnmzsGoDEF9yC0T1dc3waD0UVC5aJ9aGa6gkmkgMmiFM6kuekcAEYJAAmSxWCQQ05QsEAZgkABZESs-gh2GxMBQIAALMiUGhTQQ5RDYABKABkAMrE8hkilUOjZLj4ODZXrCOAQIh6XrUNlkuyrcL-QmmbTkCS4ChcyygtBYPCEYicmi0CUk8mqmi9bgpYqlerdYHS1qRaKKxLJVLpRByuDCTC9RWFJ0yvYHYgnBbnFWU6h2qxAA)

**UPDATE**

TS version: `4.5.5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the return type of your function to `[Error, null] | [null, number[]]`:

```
function makeUpdateParams(code: string | null, list: Array<{ version: number[] }>): [Error, null] | [null, number[]] {
  if (!code) return [new Error('code is empty'), null]
  return [null, list.flatMap(i => i.version)];
}

function updateVersion(versions: number[]) { }

function main() {
  const list = [{ version: [1, 2] }, { version: [3, 4] }];
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const [err, params] = makeUpdateParams(searchParams.get('code'), list);
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  updateVersion(params);
}
```

---

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYGsCmBVADgE1SkwAVUAnVZAZwAoI59MAuRaqcmMAc0QB9EYEABthAGkTCY7VgEFylAJ4AeAN6IAbpnLV4YVkOQAjbQG0AuogC+APgCUrUwFEFcchKGjLA05-GCQYzNzS1UAKEREGGBEWgBCBiY7RHJMKBByJF9MAHdEF3I3WgByRMwo6kRMZFwoRWK7DxFhcwiUtIysvwkpdgA6YGEiAFlUXFoYRABeGyi+rR09O3MAbjCrMLDQSFgERBACIkwANW1dBFoF87BqA0CTcgtk9Q2t8Gg9FFQuWme2hhuUEk0iBU0QpnUVz0jgAjBIAEyWKwSSFnaHggDMEgALEjVv8EOw2JgKBAABZkSg0aaCXKIbAAJQAMgBlEnkcmUqh0HJcfBwHJ9YRwCBEPR9ajs8l2NaRAFE0zadyIXAUbmWMFoLB4QjELk0WiS0kUtU0PrcNIlMoNHogmVtaKxJXJVLpTKIeVwYSYPpKorO2X7Q7EU6LC6qqnUe1WIA)

Comment: Or just cut out the middleman entirely and go for `Error | number[]`.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Indeed. The function design is a bit old school.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say, my TS version is `4.5.2`. It seems doesn't work. You can try `4.5.5` in playground

Comment: It works fine for `v4.7.4`.

Comment: Yeah... the control flow analysis for [destructured descriminating unions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6-rc/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions) was improved in 4.6. There are workarounds like the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66807259/typescript-narrowing-down-within-union-of-tuples), but if it was up to me, I'd just rework my function, or add an `if (params) updateVersion(params)` check.